# Calculate percentages in groupby, based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions, percentage

I have a table like:

| Month | Binary | Value_missing | Total_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | N | 40 | 120 |
| 1 | Y | 5 | 50 |
| 2 | N | 30 | 200 |
| 2 | Y | 10 | 20 |

I want to calculate in pandas a groupby that gives me a percentage of the column Value_missing based on the Total_value. I expected to get:

| Month | Binary | Value_missing | Total_value | %_Value_missing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | N | 40 | 120 | 0,235 |
| 1 | Y | 5 | 50 | 0,029 |
| 2 | N | 30 | 200 | 0,1363 |
| 2 | Y | 10 | 20 | 0,045 |

For each row/ cell in the column Value_missing, I want to divide by the sum of Total_Value aggregated by month

An example of the calculus off the first row: 40 / (120 + 50) = 0,235

Thank you!

Comment: You probably forgot to mention, you want to groupby month?

Comment: Yes. For each cell in the column Value_missing, I want to divide by the sum of Total_Value by month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
df['%_Value_missing'] = df['Value_missing'].div(df.groupby('Month')['Total_value'].transform(sum))
```

Alternative:

```
df['%_Value_missing'] = df.groupby('Month').apply(lambda x: x['Value_missing'] / x['Total_value'].sum()).values
```

OUTPUT:

```
   Month Binary  Value_missing  Total_value  %_Value_missing
0      1      N             40          120         0.235294
1      1      Y              5           50         0.029412
2      2      N             30          200         0.136364
3      2      Y             10           20         0.045455
```

Some performance comparisons:

```
%%timeit
df['Value_missing'].div(df.groupby('Month')['Total_value'].transform(sum))
541 µs ± 19.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
df.groupby('Month').apply(lambda x: x['Value_missing'] / x['Total_value'].sum()).values
1.55 ms ± 4.61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```